# Configuring CronTriggerFactoryBean for quartz clustering with JobStoreTX

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

We are using Quartz 2.1.5; we have the following properties set:

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.CloudscapeDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = true
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval=20000
```

and the following beans configuration:

```
<bean name="abcRequestsJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.hsc.correspondence.job.AbcRequestsJob" />
    <property name="group" value="sftpTransfers"/>
</bean>


<bean id="abcRequestsJobTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="abcRequestsJob" />
    <property name="group" value="sftpTransfers"/>
    <property name="cronExpression" value="${quartz.abcRequests.cronExpression}" />
</bean>
```

When we run, we are getting an error saying that

```
nested exception is org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't store trigger 'sftpTransfers.abcRequestsJobTrigger' for 'sftpTransfers.abcRequestsJob' 
job:JobDataMap values must be Strings when the 'useProperties' property is set.  
Key of offending value: jobDetail 
[See nested exception: java.io.IOException: JobDataMap values must be Strings when the 'useProperties' property is set. Key of offending value: jobDetail]
```

Is there another way to configure a `CronTriggerFactoryBean` than using a reference to the `JobDetailFactoryBean` reference, or a different trigger factory bean that only takes strings as properties?  This all worked before we wanted to use clustering, but now that the job is going to be written to a blob they want only strings to be persisted.  That's fine, how do I get it done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer:

http://site.trimplement.com/using-spring-and-quartz-with-jobstore-properties/
http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-130984.html

Problem:

This happens with Spring Framework and Quartz together when using `org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=true`, meaning that all Job data is stored in the database as properties instead of serialized Java objects.

Error is because of Spring class `CronTriggerFactoryBean` that stores a reference to the `JobDetail` in the `JobDataMap`, which cannot be represented as a set of properties.

`CronTriggerFactoryBean` is setting the jobDetail into the trigger's `jobDataMap`.

Workaround:

Extend `CronTriggerFactoryBean` and remove `JobDetail` from `jobDataMap`.

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailAwareTrigger;

public class PersistableCronTriggerFactoryBean extends CronTriggerFactoryBean {

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        super.afterPropertiesSet();

        //Remove the JobDetail element
        getJobDataMap().remove(JobDetailAwareTrigger.JOB_DETAIL_KEY);
    }
}
```