# Upgrading to Spring 4.1 Breaks Quartz Persistence due to removed JobDetailAwareTrigger

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, spring-4

I am upgrading from Spring 3.2.x to **Spring 4.1.x** and am using **Quartz 2.2.1**.  We dynamically create jobs and have been persisting them using the solution described in [this stackoverlow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17567992/291612).

The solution in that answer depends on a constant defined by `JobDetailAwareTrigger.JOB_DETAIL_KEY`, however that interface has been removed from the code base as a result of the work done for [Spring JIRA 11262](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11262), and now my code does not compile.

I investigated the [github commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/ea1e27efa29b27530a21362236137240006bc2f8#diff-1fb8a2b2f6caa0f584b17e6b45f197f9L236) that removed the interface and found that internal Spring code now directly references "jobDetail" literals when needed rather than a constant. Should I follow suit and create my own jobDetail constant that is defined within my application, and then reference that everywhere where I had previously referenced `JobDetailAwareTrigger.JOB_DETAIL_KEY`?  If I do that, am I now making my application vulnerable to an unlikely future Spring change to the definition of "jobDetail"?

**EDIT:**

I created my own `final static String JOB_DETAIL_KEY = "jobDetail"` constant for use in my code and everything functioned with that change.  I still feel uneasy about defining a constant that was pulled from a value used internally within the Spring code

```
public interface JobService {
    public static final String JOB_DETAIL_KEY = "jobDetail";
    ....
}

public class PersistableCronTriggerFactoryBean extends CronTriggerFactoryBean {

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws ParseException {
        //We run everything on UTC.
        setTimeZone(DateTimeZone.UTC.toTimeZone());
        super.afterPropertiesSet();

        //Remove the JobDetail element
        //Note that Quartz useProperties is set to true
        getJobDataMap().remove(JobService.JOB_DETAIL_KEY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901922/spring-4-0-6-with-quartz-1-8-6-setcronexpression-method-is-not-exposed-to-cron/27917980#27917980), I think its better to define jobs and triggers  this way.

Comment: @yishaiz I do use the CronTriggerFactoryBean and JobDetailFactory bean, but it in a way to facilitate dynamically created jobs as opposed to statically defined jobs.  I added some code to my question to illustrate the approach I use per the answer that I linked to in my question - credit where credit is due :)  My issue is that the definition of the key used to remove the jobDetail from the JobDataMap was removed from Spring 4, and now I must create my own definition of that key with a value gleaned from the Spring code. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Jeff M I am also facing the same error. what needs to done to resolve the issue.

Comment: @SandeepChoudhari, it has been quite some time since that project so the details have faded from my mind. However, I think if you just follow what I did in my Edit in the original post, you should be able to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, the `JobDetailAwareTrigger` no longer existed after Spring 4.0.9.RELEASE.

I don't think you need to worry about future Spring changes will bring any harm to your project after adding your own 'JOB_DETAIL_KEY', because the `JobDataMap` is under control of quartz.